# How to clean messy CSV files with regex commands in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, csv

I'm dealing with messy CSV files, and really hope some regexes (or other viable substitutions) will help. Thousands of files per day, thousands of lines per file, hundreds of columns. For the most part the CSVs are very well formatted - all fields are contained within "quotes" and are comma-delimited. However, what's inside the fields sometimes causes trouble.

For simplicity, here's a brief demonstration of the issues I'm running into.

**Example data:**

```
"option1","option2","product","description","reference","price","currency","foo","bar","address1","address2","city","state","postal","country","option3","option4","option5"  
"","","apples","multi-color ""macintosh"" apples","PO#1-3503", 24.00"" x 12.00"" x 12.00"","12.50","USD","","","1234 Main Street ""","","Genericsberg","VA","10324","USA","","",""
```

**Issues:**

- """ appearing some place or other ... see *address1*
- "" appearing inside of fields ... see *description*, *reference*
- " appearing inside of fields ... see *reference* - the purchase order # and product dimensions are part of the same field (don't let the ", fool you)

**What I'm pretty sure I want:**

1. when "" appears inside of a non-empty field, remove it
2. when ", appears inside of a field, remove the " but keep the comma
3. when """ appears at the beginning / end of a field, change it to "
4. when "" appears at the beginning / end of a non-empty field, change it to "

What I really want is for these messy CSVs to import properly, with the data arriving in the correct fields.

**Background:**

Our tech stack involves Ruby on Rails, currently using SmarterCSV to import CSV files from an S3 bucket.

**What we've tried:**

`text.gsub(/(?<!^|,)"(?!,|$)/, '')`

This has served us well for various issues up to this point, but not so well on the above.

`text.gsub('"""', '"')`

This seems to accomplish # 3 well enough - haven't deployed it to production as I'd like to get past these other issues as well.

Comment: Additional note - these CSVs come from an outside source over which we have zero control, and they are the *only* data source.

Comment: The escaped double-quote `""` inside a double-quote-delimited csv field should be importable without a hitch, but this makes no sense to me `,"PO#1-3503", 24.00"" x 12.00"" x 12.00"",` because I can see no reason for an exporter to generate that as one field. Are you sure this structure turns up?

Comment: To just remove the properly escaped double-quotes you could use a variation of your first expression; something like `""(?!,|$)` and replace with the empty string.

Comment: To be clear, are you sure the aforementioned structure turns up in your _source_ data? That looks more like a product of improper double-quote substitution.

Comment: You are sure all of these are the same encoding?

Comment: Am I correct in concluding that it is beside the point that these troublesome strings are contained in CSV files? Assuming you know how to read and write CSV files aren't you really just asking how to modify strings by a set of rules? If so, I suggest you edit your question (including the title) to remove all references to CSV files and just make it a problem concerning strings.  Also, when giving examples it's best to make them as short as you can (while retaining essential elements) and show the desired result, even when you think that should be obvious from your statement of the problem.

Comment: Once you figure out how to modify the strings you might consider using a *custom converter* for implementing that. Search for "custom converters" [here](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html).